# Trigger on only one of multiple polled SCMs in a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins

My Jenkinsfile has two SCM checkouts, `primary`, and `secondary`. I only want to have the build triggered when commits are made in `primary`. I've set the `poll` argument in the obvious way, but it does not seem to be honored; the build gets triggered when commits are made to either repository.

```
node {
    stage("checkout") {
        checkout scm: [$class: "MercurialSCM", source: "/var/jenkins_home/hg/primary", subdir: "hg/primary", clean: true], poll: true
        checkout scm: [$class: "MercurialSCM", source: "/var/jenkins_home/hg/secondary", subdir: "hg/secondary", clean: true], poll: false
    }
    stage("do something") {
        echo 'Hello World'
        sh 'sleep 30s'
        echo 'Done'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out how to do this from within Jenkinsfile only.
To solve this problem for myself, I ended up creating a separate Jenkins job (Free Style project, not pipeline) which was setup to Poll SCM on the `primary` repo.  This job does nothing except in the `Post-build Actions` it triggers my actual Jenkins Pipeline job which loads the Jenkinsfile like you showed.
The trigger passes a `Predefined parameter` set to the change ID that the poller found.  In my case it was Git so I set `change=${GIT_COMMIT}`.

In my Pipeline job, I created a String parameter called `change`.

In my Jenkinsfile, I used `env.change` in the checkout line to checkout the specific commit.